# Get exception "Object.keys called on non-object while trying to access object" while trying to get all field in request.body Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a piece of code for PUT method like this

```
module.exports.addRoutes = function(server) {
     //PUT
    server.put('/api/public/place/:id', function(request, response) {
         //this is just for testing, please do not care about the id
         var placedetail = request.body;
         for(var key in placedetail)
         {
              console.log(placedetail[key]);
         }
    });
};
```

In this code, I want to get all the request body field, like request.body.name , request.body.email, etc. The field parameter will be decided by the user , the server will get the value by key.

For example, a user put the data in the request like

```
{
name:"Test"
email:"abc@gmail.com"
}
```

another user put the data like

```
    {
    address:"Test"
    location:"Some Test String"
    }
```

I use this way and got the exception "Object.keys called on non-object while trying to access object". But when access each field , for example: request.body.name, request.body.email , it still get the parameter succesfully.

I also you another to way to parse the data by JSON.parse(request.body.toString()), but actually , the data is not JSON and can not parse.

How can I get all fields of request.body?

Thanks.

Comment: What do `console.log(typeof request.body)` and `console.log(typeof placedetail)` output?

Comment: does the request data have to be in that format?  As you said, it is not JSON, nor is it any standard format.  The only way to parse that would be to manually tokenize the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) module to parse the req.body data:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: I have included it in my app.js before :)